Интеллект-карта с прогресс-баром для Obsidian
Всем доброго времени суток!
Прошу подсказать, т.к. возможно это уже реализовано, но найти соответствующий плагин в Obsidian я не смог.
Требуется создать интеллект-карту с возможностью отслеживания прогресса выполнения. Подобная функция хорошо реализована в приложении "Taskade" и выглядит следующим образом:

Что-то подобное хотелось бы и сделать в Obsidian, т.к. сейчас веду там свою базу заметок и прочего, а вот такой функции не хватает. Что-то похожее смог реализовать с помощью плагинов "Task Progress Bar" и "Mindmap Nextgen", но проблема в том, что не отображается общий прогресс на самой карте, т.е. необходимо открывать еще и окно с задачами, а также на карте очень странно отображаются чек-боксы, т.е. почему-то они горят [х], когда задача не закрыта и выглядит это всё следующим образом:

